# call one spider from another spider in a web crawler made using scrapy

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, scrapy, web-crawler

I want to hit all the links on a web page where pdf files lie and store these pdf files on my system.

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


class spider_a(BaseSpider):
    name = "Colleges"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.abc.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.abc.org/appwebsite.html",
        "http://www.abc.org/misappengineering.htm",
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(response.body)
        for link in soup.find_all('a'):
            download_link = link.get('href')
            if '.pdf' in download_link:
                pdf_url = "http://www.abc.org/" + download_link
                print pdf_url
```

with the above code I am able to find the links on intended pages where pdf files lie

```
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class FileSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "fspider"
    allowed_domains = ["www.aicte-india.org"]
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.abc.org/downloads/approved_institut_websites/an.pdf#toolbar=0&zoom=85"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
```

And with this code I can save the body of the pages listed in `start_urls`.

Is there a way to join both these spiders so that I can save these pdfs by running my crawler?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need two spiders?

```
from urlparse import urljoin
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector

class spider_a(BaseSpider):
    ...
    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        for href in hxs.select('//a/@href[contains(.,".pdf")]'):
            yield Request(urljoin(response.url, href),
                    callback=self.save_file)

    def save_file(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-1]
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
```

Comment: Hi @steven thanks for the help

but I am getting the following error:

exceptions.AttributeError: 'HtmlXPathSelector' object has no attribute 'find'

Comment: That's because you need to use `select`, not `find`... if you are using Scrapy, you don't need Beautiful Soup.